# Datasource for regression model prediction : Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to work using Amazon machine learning, but the data set that I have is small. The model I want to build is for regression based predictions and the domain I am aiming for the data set to belong is financial, say product price prediction, price and demand prediction based on macro/micro economic factor.

I am looking for a data set that contains factors that lead to variations in value of a product or commodity. For example, I would like to predict the value of 1 unit of polyester yarn after 1 year.  The factors which influence the yarn price are say - prices of crude oil, GDP of country,figures of IIP, inflation etc. So I would like a data set that contains the quotes of these factors on which the final price depends.

I find difficulty assembling this data myself because I don't know all the factors that contribute to a certain predictive price. Does anyone know of a dataset I can start with that sounds like it might contain these factors?

Answer (score 6):

There are [multiple datasets](http://quant.caltech.edu/historical-stock-data.html) available in the internet but you need to pay for most of them.
One of the best datasets for starting (and it is free) is the *Quantquote Free dataset*.

You can download it from [here](http://quantquote.com/files/quantquote_daily_sp500_83986.zip).

This is the description (borrowed from their [website](https://quantquote.com/historical-stock-data)):

> This collection of daily resolution data goes back to 1998 for all symbols currently active in the S&P500. It is updated quarterly, the last update was 07/31/2013.

Comment: i have made changes in my question , can you please have a re-look and suggest me data that belongs to the changes in question. i am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Given your new question, I suggest you to split it in two different questions: one asking for help on the predicition variables and the other asking for the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Housing prices is a popular regression data set. [Here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data) is one example.

Car prices is an other popular choice. [Here](https://www.kaggle.com/orgesleka/used-cars-database) is one example.

Remember there is "no free lunch" in machine learning. Models tend to **not** generalize across domains.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [UCL Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html). You will find the various data sets by algorithms.

For example: Regression, Classification, Clustering etc.

I assure you that this will be really helpful for practicing algorithms.